# How to send request parameters withe the new Spring Boot 3.2 RestClient?

Tags: spring-boot

I have looked at the examples and the javadoc but I can't find an example anywhere.

I am migrating from WebClient to the new RestClient.

I have looked online in the obvious places.

I am trying to send 5 parameters and a path variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example of using RestClient:

```
RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder()
      .baseUrl("https://test.com/api")
      .build();

String pathVariable = "pathVariable";
ResponseEntity<String> response = restClient.get()
    .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
         .path("/" + pathVariable)
         .queryParam("param1", "value1")
         .queryParam("param2", "value2")
         .queryParam("param3", "value3")
         .queryParam("param4", "value4")
         .queryParam("param5", "value5")
         .build())
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .retrieve()
    .toEntity(String.class)
    .block();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [method `uri(String uri, Object... uriVariables)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestClient.UriSpec.html#uri(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) to specify parameters, as shown in this [blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2023/07/13/new-in-spring-6-1-restclient#exchange) from Spring:

```
restClient.get()
  .uri("https://petclinic.example.com/pets/{id}", id)
  // ..
```

Comment: those are url parameters, I was asking about request parameters.